# Sitecore, moving item takes multiple tries

Tags: sitecore

I have a saving event handler in Sitecore where when the date of an item changes (from say 8/7/2014 to 9/7/2014) I want it to be moved into another folder.

It currently somewhat does that, but only if I change the date twice.

If I go from 8/7/2014 > 9/6/2014 it does nothing. If I then change the same item's date to 9/7/2014 it moves it into the correct folder.

If I debug the code it follows the exact same path both times .. anyone have a reason as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Post your code and event configuration

Comment: Looks like I fixed this myself... Apparently the saving handler has access to the item before and after it's saved or the new and old values of each property before and after a save. Basically the event was running twice - once with the new date, once with the old and since the old date was processing last, the item appeared to not be moving anywhere. Changed it to use the item:saved event and everything's working as expected.

Comment: Can you please share your saved event code here so we can debug that

Comment: @YogeshSharma Working code has been added. As I mentioned in the comment above yours, the saving handler was running twice,  once with the new date value, once with the old. Changing to the saved handler worked much better because I only have access to the newly saved values, not the old and new values.

Comment: @Ben Great finding :)

Comment: @Ben Can you please share your answer (and what the problem was) as a real answer and mark this question as resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the other problems was that the saving handler was running twice, once with the new date value, once with the old. Changing to the saved handler worked much better because I only have access to the newly saved values, not the old and new values.

Since there were a few comments asking for it, here's the working code to move and item from folder parent to parent > year > month. Keep in mind this is using glassmapper so it would be slightly different if not using glass mapper.

```
    protected void MoveItemToMonthDateFolder<T>(T scItem, Func<T, DateTime> dateSelector, Models.Item parentFolder) where T : Models.Item
    {
        var date = dateSelector(scItem);

        if (!parentFolder.Children.Any(x => x.Name.Contains(date.Year.ToString())))
        {
            var yearFolder = sitecoreService.Create(parentFolder, new Folder { Name = date.Year.ToString() });
            var monthFolder = sitecoreService.Create(yearFolder, new Folder { Name = date.Month.ToString() });
            sitecoreService.Move(scItem, monthFolder);
        }
        else
        {
            var yearFolder = parentFolder.Children.First(x => x.Name.Equals(date.Year.ToString(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

            var monthFolder = yearFolder.Children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(date.Month.ToString(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

            if (monthFolder == null)
            {
                monthFolder = sitecoreService.Create(yearFolder, new Folder { Name = date.Month.ToString() });
            }
            sitecoreService.Move(scItem, monthFolder);
        }
    }
```